# Combine two datasets based on a single column time stamps which are different to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine two dataset according to similar timestamps. Both datasets have different stamps format as follow:

DF1

```
d1 = {'col1': ["a1-20220517-183028.spc", "a2-20220518-183028.spc","a3-20220519-183028.spc","a4-20220525-183028.spc"], 
      'col2': [a, b ,c,d]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

DF2

```
d2 = {'col1.2': ["18-05-2022 12:23","17-05-2022 0:16:00" ,"25-05-2022 20:23","19-05-2022 14:54","02-05-2022 12:14"], 
      'col2.2': [12, 2 ,3,10, 1]}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

I want to combine df_1 and df_2 according to the timestamp of col1 in DF1 AND col1.2 in DF2,
so the resulting output is given as follow:

```
d_output = {'col1': ["17-05-2022", "18-05-2022", "19-05-2022", "25-05-2022"], 
            'col2': [a, b ,c , d], 
            'col3': [2, 12 ,10, 3 ]}

df_output=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have tried extracting the timestamp of one and formatting it into the same format but I am really struggling to format it correctly and merge both datasets with a similar timestamp.

Anyway I could solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with a bit of pre-processing using [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
out = (
 df_1.assign(col1=pd.to_datetime(df_1['col1'].str.extract('-(\d{8})', expand=False))
                    .dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
     .merge(
  df_2.rename(columns={'col1.2': 'col1', 'col2.2': 'col3'})
      .assign(col1=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['col1']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')),
         how='left', on='col1'
     )
)
```

Output:

```
         col1 col2  col3
0  17-05-2022    a     2
1  18-05-2022    b    12
2  19-05-2022    c    10
3  25-05-2022    d     3
```

Comment: That's a great one thank you very much! For the purpose of clarification, could you please break it down in parts so that I can follow please? thanks again!

Comment: The two parts are `df_1.assign(col1=pd.to_datetime(df_1['col1'].str.extract('-(\d{8})', expand=False)).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))` and `df_2.rename(columns={'col1.2': 'col1', 'col2.2': 'col3'}).assign(col1=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['col1']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))` they are used to normalize the column names and dtypes.